# Is it possible to enable SPF, DKIM and DMARC for emails sent via GMAIL APIs?

Tags: gmail, gmail-api, gmail-addons

As the title states, has anybody successfully enabled the 3 security mechanisms for emails they have sent via [gmail apis](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/messages/send)?

Currently all emails i sent via the gmail-api (http) send, are successfully received by the recipient but has no security markings whatsoever.  This applies both for our chrome extension and gmail-addon.

Comment: Do you have your own domain? If so try to read an implement the instructions in the following documentation. 
[SPF](https://support.google.com/a/answer/33786), [DKIM](https://support.google.com/a/answer/174124), [DMARC](https://support.google.com/a/answer/2466580?hl=en&ref_topic=2759254)
If possible some information to reproduce your error will be helpful. Maybe the request you are doing right now o a more detailed explanation of your current setup.
Also could you provide the code you are using to make the call? Which endpoint are you using?

Comment: @Raserhin thank you very much for your response. I was out for vacation for a bit and failed to see your answer earlier. Currently, I am developing a gmail addon that creates eml files on the fly and send it to multiple recipients. The emails sent by the gmail addon do not have any of the security markings.

Comment: Just to add, currently I use the GMAIL-http apis to submit a request to send an email (RFC-822) . The url is as follows : 'https://www.googleapis.com/upload/gmail/v1/users/me/messages/send?uploadType=multipart'. Is there anyway to activate the security mechanisms when using this api? Thanks

Comment: GovZ have you found a way to do this?

Comment: @BaoNhan Unfortunately, I have still not found a way to do this.

Comment: @GovZ I do use Gmail APIs to send emails, and I can see SPF/DKIM marks in the email that it sends. The thing is: if you send emails to your own domain, for example from aaa@yourdomain.com to bbb@yourdomain.com (using Gmail API), then you won't see the marks. You have to send it to another domain (you can try xxx@hotmail.com), then when you open the recipient's email as a raw message, you should be able to see the SPF/DKIM marks.